# What causes inconsistency of displaying Questions when Tags is selected

Tags: bug, tags, caching

Say you remove some tag from a bunch of Questions, and then click on that Tag to see what other Questions remain.

Very often you'll find some of the same Questions from which you've removed the tag, which is probably a performance measure.

You then go back and do some more editing, and then click on that Tag again, and you see even more Questions than before (from which you removed that Tag).

What causes this?

Comment: Caching of course, what else? The caching is rather short, the posts will be gone from the page in a few minutes.

Comment: But it shows more cached stuff than the previous time?

Comment: I've never seen that specifically but the site is served by a cluster of machines, I can imagine that the caching isn't entirely consistent across them for short periods of time.